# How to pass a dataframe itself to a function as an argument using interact of ipywidgets but without fixed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am new to interact and i would like to select name of functions among options through a dropdown list. These functions are already defined an each of them have different type of arguments and most of them accept a dataframe as an argument.
I would like to build a structure that user pick a function among the list then arguments of the function also shown to be filled.

I am having difficulties passing dataframe as an argument to earlier selected function because name of dataframe is not fixed so i could not use fixed of widgets. If i assign dataframe directly then columns of dataframe shown that is also useless for me because i want entire dataframe to be passed to the function.
Is there a way to pass dataframe as an argument to the function via widgets interact?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.
[image]

```
functionpicker=widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[
     'func1','func2','func3'] ,
    value='func1',    
    style = {'description_width': 'initial'},
    description='SELECT FUNC:',
   disabled=False
)

display(functionpicker)

def func1(df,dat1,dat2,dat3):
    print(df)
    print(dat1)
    print(dat2)
    print(dat3)
def run_selected(picked):
    if picked == 'func1' :
        interact(func1,df=df,dat1='dat1',dat2='dat2',dat3='dat3')
```

Comment: question unclear. What do you want to have exactly? What is ``func1`` and what do you mean with 'pass dataframe to the function? As far as I understand, if user select ``func1`` from ``SELECT FUNC:`` dropdown, the you will ``dat1``, ``dat2``, and ``dat3`` as ``str`` printed out. Is it what you want or do you want to have 3 more dropdown lists?

Comment: I want user select function from dropdown list and arguments need by choosed function to be passed again by user in boxes below just appear after function is choosed.No problem for me up to this point.My problem is one of the arguments required by these functions is a dataframe object itself mostly.But i could not manage to pass a dataframe object through widgets.Using fixed option is not solution for me because different  dataframe object may need to be entered by user.

Comment: I don't understand. I'll try to write the code as my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
functions = ['select func', 'func1', 'func2']

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(5)*2
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x, 'y1': y})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': x, 'y2': y})
data = [df1, df2]
def selectfunc(func):
    if func == 'func1':
        def selectdata(data):
            if data == 'df1':
                print(df1)
            elif data == 'df2':
                print(df2)
        wg.interact(selectdata, data=['df1', 'df2'])
    elif func == 'func2':
        print('this is func2')
    
wg.interact(selectfunc, func=functions)
```

Comment: Structure is as you build Karina but there is an import difference that user will  not enter name of dataframe from a dropdpwn list instead he will enter manually so name of dataframe could be anything.Thats why i am having difficulties.Because i could not find a way user enter dataframe as an dataframe object.Widgets only allow what user enter free text to be accept as  a string. But in order to solve my problem it should be taken as a dataframe.Imagine that user enter dfx and you should print dfx itself in below not 'dfx' string.I hope i am clear now :)

Comment: what do you mean by _user enter name of dataframe_? Who is _user_ in this case? code developer? If you mean an actual user who just run the above code, they will not _enter_ anything, since it's a dropdown, not an input field label. So no keyboard input is required at all in this case.